# Absolute values and Quadratic

Tags: quadratics, absolute-value

The difference of the roots of the quadratic equation $x^2 + bx + c = 0$ is $|b - 2c|$. If $c \neq 0$, then find $c$ in terms of $b$.

I know Vieta, for sum and product of roots of a quadratic, but am not seeing how to apply any of those tools to find the absolute difference $|b-2c|.$ I'm definitely missing a nice trick to do this. Solutions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You could find the difference of the roots using the quadratic formula

Comment: @Fleccerd Can you derive a general explicit formula for the difference of the roots in terms of the coefficients?

Answer (score 3):

From the quadratic formula, one root is $\dfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}}2$, and the other is $\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4c}}2$,

so the difference is $\sqrt{b^2-4c}$.

So we have $b^2-4c=(b-2c)^2=b^2-4bc+4c^2$, or $4c^2+4c-4bc=0$.

If $c\ne0$, that means $4c+4-4b=0$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: I got c = b-1, and it's correct! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

One could also approach the question in this way.  We are given that the difference between the two zeroes of this (monic) quadratic polynomial is $ \ |b - 2c| \ \ . $  Since we cannot distinguish the  relative "order" of the zeroes in the abstract, we may simply designate them $ \ r \ $ and $ \ r + b - 2c \ \ . $

The factorization of the polynomial is then $ \ (x - r)·(x - r - b + 2c) \ \ , $ thereby giving us
$$ x^2 + bx + c \ \ = \ \ x^2 \ + \ (-b + 2c - 2r)·x \ + \ (r^2 + rb - 2rc) \ \ . $$

Consequently,
$$ b \ = \ -b + 2c - 2r \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2b \ = \ 2c - 2r \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ b \ = \ c - r \ \ ; $$
$$ c \ = \ r^2 + rb - 2rc \ = \ r^2 + r·(c - r) - 2rc \ = \ r^2 + rc - r^2 - 2rc \ = \ -rc \ \ . $$

We find that $ \ c + rc \ = \ c·(1 + r) \ = \ 0 \ \ . $  Since the stated conditions *exclude* $ \ c = 0 \ \ , $ we conclude that $ \ r = -1 \ \ , $ and thus $ \ b \ = \ c - (-1) \ \Rightarrow \ c \ = \ b - 1 \ \ . $

Note that although the problem statement places no restrictions on the zeroes being real *versus*  complex, we see that one and therefore *both* zeroes are real.

**EDIT (9/26) --**  After a little further investigation, I find that the relation *also* works if we permit $ \ b \ $ and $ \ c \ $ to be complex.  The polynomial $ \ z^2 + (\alpha \ + \ \beta·i)·z + \ ([\alpha - 1]  \ + \ \beta·i) \ $ has the one real zero $ \ -1 \ $ and one complex zero which differs by $ \ |b - 2c| \ \ . $